# How to merge and delete the files in unix?

Tags: bash, unix, cat

i would like to merge multiple files into single file in bash. so i use the code,

cat file1 file2 file3 file4 >> output

But because my computer has low memory i am not able to create the merged file. instead do you know how to simultaneously remove file1 file2 file3 once the data has been added to output file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i in file1 file2 file3 file4 ; do cat "$i" >> output && rm "$i" || break ; done
```

So for each file, it will append the contents to `output` and remove the source file once appended. If anything goes wrong, it stops.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of is:

```
mv file1 output
cat file2 >> output && rm file2 &&
cat file3 >> output && rm file3
```

The `rm`s here are at pretty much the earliest useful opportunity.

You can, of course, do this in a `for` loop.

```
mv file1 output
for f in file*; do
   cat $f >> output && rm $f
done
```